# UnboundLocalError:local variable 'final_result' referenced before assignment..django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I am a beginner in Programming and Django. I am making a calculator. but I am getting an error(UnboundLocalError:local variable 'final_result' referenced before assignment).The code is

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
import re

def clculator(request):
    pass


def calculation(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        values = request.POST['values']
        print(values)
        vals = re.findall(r"(\d+)", values)
        operators=['+','x','÷','-','.','%']
        opr = []

        for v in values:
            for o in operators:
                if v == o:
                    opr.append(o)
            
        print(opr)
        print(re.findall(r"(\d+)", values))

        for o in (opr):
            if o=='.':
                i=opr.index(o)
                res=vals[i]+"."+vals[i+1]
                vals.remove(vals[i+1])
                opr.remove(opr[i])
                vals[i]=res
                print(vals)
                print(opr)

        for o in opr:
            if o == '%':
                i = opr.index(o)
                res =(float(vals[i])/100)*float(vals[i+1])
                vals.remove(vals[i+1])
                opr.remove(opr[i])
                vals[i]= res
                print(vals)
                print(opr)
              
        for o in opr:
            if o == '÷':
                i = opr.index(o)
                res = float(vals[i])/float(vals[i+1])
                vals.remove(vals[i+1])
                opr.remove(opr[i])
                vals[i] = str(res)
                print(vals)
                print(opr)


        for o in opr:
            if o == 'x':
                i = opr.index(o)
                res = float(vals[i])*float(vals[i+1])
                vals.remove(vals[i+1])
                opr.remove(opr[i])
                vals[i] = str(res)
                print(vals)
                print(opr)

        for o in opr:
            if o == '+':
                i = opr.index(o)
                res = float(vals[i])+float(vals[i+1])
                vals.remove(vals[i+1])
                opr.remove(opr[i])
                vals[i] = str(res)
                print(vals)
                print(opr)
                

        for o in opr:
            if o == '-':
                i = opr.index(o)
                res = float(vals[i])-float(vals[i+1])
                vals.remove(vals[i+1])
                opr.remove(opr[i])
                vals[i] = str(res)
                print(vals)
                print(opr)

        if len(opr) != 0:
            if opr[0] == '÷':
                result = float(vals[0])/float(vals[1])
            elif opr[0] == 'x':
                result = float(vals[0])*float(vals[1])
            elif opr[0] == '+':
                result = float(vals[0])+float(vals[1])
            else:
                result = float(vals[0])-float(vals[1])

        else:
            result = float(vals[0])


        final_result = round(result,2)
        print(final_result)


    return render(request, 'calc/index.html', {'result':final_result, 'values':values})
```

I don't know where the problem is.Please help me with this problem

Comment: Your variable is on set on a POST. You seem to do a GET .

Comment: Take another, closer look at the error message. It tells you what line the error is on, and even lists the line. That is why the guidelines insist that you *include the full stack trace* in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the variable `final_result` is inside  `if request.method == "POST":`. But you've used it inside return statement which is outsite if. If this is suppose to be only for "POST" then add spaces to return statement so that it aling with `if request.method == "POST":`. Then erorr should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the variables 'final_result' and 'values' before the if statement.
Here is a good source to learn more about scope https://pythonspot.com/scope/ .